# How can i convert an array in Json string to c# object?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json return result like the following:

Json =

{
"Id":"12345",
"FirstName":"Bob",
"LastName":"Builder",
"Links":[]
}

Links can have a list of objects of type LinkService, i want to cast even if the array is empty , so in c# i get an empty array.

I do the following

```
      var token = JObject.Parse(Json);
      var Id = token.Value<string>("Id");
      var fname = token.Value<string>("FirstName");
      var lbname = token.Value<bool>("LastName");
      var links = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<LinkService>>(token.Value<Array>("Links"));
```

Issue is that it says cant convert System.Array to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader

Comment: You're trying to deserialize json passing an object as an argument. You need to pass json instead or use different approach. Try using `token["Lingks"].ToString()` instead or as Amir suggested - `.ToObject`

Comment: Why the hassle with tokens? Create a proper model and just deserialize to it.

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/aHNDyy

Comment: What Amir suggested works fine, but as Fildor suggested , it would be better and cleaner to create a proper model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the jToken to an object using the [ToObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) method:

```
var links = token["Links"].TObject<List<LinkService>>();
```